# Why is List<List<Integer>> updated even though its not a global variable?

Tags: java, methods, global-variables

allpaths is a List> defined in findPaths(...) method which calls dfs(...) method within its scope, but I dont understand why is allpaths updated since its not a global variable? So, how is allpaths List updating after dfs method is called?

```
import java.util.*;

class TreeNode {
  int val;
  TreeNode left;
  TreeNode right;

  TreeNode(int x) {
    val = x;
  }
};

class FindAllTreePaths {
  public static List<List<Integer>> findPaths(TreeNode root, int sum) {
    List<List<Integer>> allpaths = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> cpath = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    dfs(root, sum, cpath, allpaths);
    return allpaths;
  }
  private static void dfs(TreeNode root, int sum, List<Integer> cpath, List<List<Integer>> result){
    if(root == null){
      return;
    }
    if(root.val == sum && root.left == null && root.right == null){
      cpath.add(root.val);
      result.add(cpath);
    }
    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    temp.addAll(cpath);
    temp.add(root.val);
    dfs(root.left, sum-root.val, temp, result);
    dfs(root.right, sum-root.val, temp, result);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(12);
    root.left = new TreeNode(7);
    root.right = new TreeNode(1);
    root.left.left = new TreeNode(4);
    root.right.left = new TreeNode(10);
    root.right.right = new TreeNode(5);
    int sum = 18;
    List<List<Integer>> result = FindAllTreePaths.findPaths(root, sum);
    System.out.println("Tree paths with sum " + sum + ": " + result);
  }
}
```

Also, I tried following code, which is scaled version of above scenario:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int c = call();
        System.out.println(c);
    }

    public static int call(){
        int c=100;
        call1(c);
        return c;
    }

    private static void call1(int d){
        c=4;
        d = 4;
    }
}
```

and the result is:
c=100

which shows that c is not global to call1().

Edit:
I tried following code since I was told reference type variables follows pass by reference, but that's not true:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        call();
    }

    public static void call(){
        String c="Jack";
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        l.add(1);
        call1(c, l);
        System.out.println(c);
        System.out.println(l.get(0) + " " + l.get(1));
    }

    private static void call1(String c, List<Integer> l){
        l.add(2);
        c="Jack Ryan";
    }
}
```

But the output is:
Jack
1 2

which implies that String is pass by value and List is pass by reference.

Comment: You explicitly mutate it using `add`, what's suprising about this?

Comment: The variable "allPaths" is defined at the class level. The 'dfs' method is also a member of the class. Class methods can access and mutate other members of the class. This is expected in Java. It sounds as if you might be coming from another language (welcome to Java if so :) ). I would recommend reading about variable scope in Java, modifiers (such as static), the difference between reference type and primitive variables, etc. These are important concepts to understand early on for Java programmers. A good resource (even if a bit outdated): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html

Comment: @KellyM Java is pass by value but since List is a class, that's why its pass by reference? If so, String is a class object as well, then shouldn't string object be as well updated in the method called within its scope?

Comment: @Rohan, Java is pass by value. A pointer to the object, not the object itself, is getting passed.  The change to the list remains because you are mutating the state of an object. The change to the String does not remain because you are performing reassignment (also Strings are immutable in Java). This article explains it better than I can: https://dzone.com/articles/pass-by-value-vs-reference-in-java

Comment: @KellyM Thank you!
If you get chance, would you be kind enough to review following post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483610/why-is-recursion-merging-list-from-two-different-recursive-calls

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's the difference between all primitive data types (int, double, ...) and references.
When you create a variable, it's value is copied, every time you pass this variable to another method. The difference between primitive data types and references is, which values they store.

### Primitive data types

store the value (e.g. a number) directly. When you pass the variable the number is copied.

### References

When you deal with object, you actually deal with references to objects. A variable, which stores an object, actually stores a reference (like an address) to this object. When you pass this variable to another method, only the address to this object is copied, what means that both methods use the exact same object in memory.

Thats why you example with the ints works as expected. If you want to actually clone an object you have to implement the `Cloneable` (`java.lang.Cloneable`) interface.

Comment: String is reference type, although pass by reference is not applied. I tried replacing int with String variable in the supporting code that I have in my original post, but it works with the concept of pass by value (which is expected).